# Regular expression with if condition for matching index and index, in shell programming

Tags: regex, shell

i want to match my 2 strings index and index1 in if condition of shell programming

i tried doing this by following

`if [[ $1 == [iI][nN][dD][eE][xX][1]? ]]; then`
         `echo "matched"`

but it is not working, here basically i want to say in my regular expression that 1 should occur either 0 or 1 time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `=~` operator to match regex and make sure to use anchors `^` and `$` to avoid matching unwanted text:

```
[[ 'index1' =~ ^[iI][nN][dD][eE][xX]1?$ ]] && echo "ok" || echo "nope"
ok

[[ 'index' =~ ^[iI][nN][dD][eE][xX]1?$ ]] && echo "ok" || echo "nope"
ok
```